# Trying to GET a Google Spreadsheet in Java is returning HTTP error 405

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, google-sheets

Been working on this all day and have gotten no where with it.

My Java code looks like this:

```
final URL url = new URL(String.format("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=%s&exportFormat=tsv&gid=0", spreadsheetId));
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();    
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",   "GoogleLogin auth=" + wiseAuth.getAuthToken());    
conn.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

conn.setDoOutput(true); // trouble here, see below

conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);    
conn.connect();
```

I always get a FileNotFound error when attempting to do `conn.getInputStream()`. I narrowed it down to being that the response code is 405 Method Not Allowed. The exception is returning me my URL and I can access the page just fine in my browser.

It was then that I discovered that `setDoOutput(true)` executes a POST internally. But if I remove that line, `conn.getInputStream()` is null, and `conn.getOutputStream()` appears to return nothing--though maybe I am setting it up wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend you to do it like this, even if you get it working now you cannot ensure you will get it working in the future if Google started changing it.

Instead, consider using [Google Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#ListingSpreadsheets). The provided Java examples are pretty straightforward and you should able to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Except that I don't believe that API lets me export/retrieve files as TSV, which is my end goal here.

Comment: Take a look at this example then: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets . It allows you to export as TSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a web debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what exactly your application is sending in the GET request and compare it to your browser. You might be missing an important header or something, and Fiddler makes it really easy to slowly strip down your browser's request to the essential elements (just drag a request to clone it, then take out headers).

Comment: Hmm--I used HTTP Client (I'm on a Mac), and I get a "(( Zero-length response returned from server. ))" response.

Comment: Bleh, I also wonder if it's because I'm accessing the URL via https.